# View Expressions curve in Graph Editor

Tags: animation, drivers, graph-editor

I've animated some channels, such as rotation channels and a modifier value using Expressions. But I can't find out how to view the resulting Driver curve in the Graph Editor. I'm using Blender 2.8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. In Blender 2.7x there was a separate Drivers section in the Graph Editor, but in Blender 2.8 it has been decoupled from the Graph Editor and now has its own dedicated Drivers editor.